# Query mongoose -- Finding all battle where opponet id equals or challanger id equals some_id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I trying to query my mongo db for all battles a player has played. I was wondering about the or operation in mongoose. I can't get it to work.

I have tried something like this:

```
var currentUser = req.params.player_id;

Battle.find({}).populate({
             path: 'utfordrer motstander',
             }).where('utfordrer.id').equals(currentUser).$or('motstander.id').equals(currentUser).exec(function (err, battle) {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else {
                    console.log(battle);
                }
        });
```

This is my battle schema:

```
   var battleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   utfordrer: {
      id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"},
      username: String,
      score: Number,
      ferdig: Boolean
   },
   motstander: {
      id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"},
      username: String,
      score: Number,
      ferdig: Boolean
   },
   spill:
       {
           id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Game"},
           navn: String,
           beskrivelse: String
       },
   tidspunkt: Date
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Battle.find({$or:[ {'utfordrer.id': currentUser}, {'motstander.id': currentUser}]}).exec(function (err, battle) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
            }else{
                console.log("===========UTFORDRINGER");
                console.log(battle.length);
               res.render("Battles/index", {antallUtfordringer: antall, battleId: utfordringBattleId});
            }
});
```

Comment: This returened every battle the user had played!